# ActionResult Details needs to resolve FK from List to display Name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, html-helper

I have a FK in my Details ViewModel and when the View binds to the ViewModel I only get the FK back (expected). The FK is a reference to a simple ID/Name type table. I also have a Strongly typed List in the VM representing that FK-referenced table. I want to do something like

```
<div class="display-field">@Model.ManufacturersList.Find(x => x.ID == Model.softwaremanufacturerid))</div>
```

While this will return the the instance I want...I can't figure out how to get the "Name" attribute to display.

Sorry if this is more a Lamda question but thought I'd try all the same

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `.ManufacturersList.Find(x => x.ID == Model.softwaremanufacturerid)` returns what you want, don't do it in the View. The View should only display data, while the model layer should really be doing the searching (`.Find`)

In your view model, add a string property for `ManufacturerName`

```
public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
```

In your controller,

```
MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel()
{
    ManufacturerName = .ManufacturersList
        .Find(x => x.ID == theFKAlreadyInTheViewModel)
};
return View(vm);
```

Then in your view,

```
@Model.ManufacturerName
```

OR, more simply, you could use the ViewBag

```
ViewBag.ManufacturerName = YourManufacturersList
    .Find(x => x.ID == theFKAlreadyInTheViewModel);
```

Then in your View,

```
@ViewBag.ManufacturerName
```

Comment: Your way is more elegant and keeps in in the VM...I got to work by simply adding ".name" to the end of the nasty lamda I did

Comment: I've found in a lot of web apps sticking to a 1:1 View:ViewModel ratio can be tedious, but worth it when you need to start refactoring. It's not always the case, though.